# PostgreSQL - Unificar (y sumar) datos de columnas repetidas

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Hola comunidad Stackover, mi duda es la siguiente.
Luego de realizar algunos INNER JOIN (en donde unifique la recaudacion de varias peliculas por paises) me quedaron 2 columnas con paises repetidos y remuneracion separada. Ej:

```
+-------------+-------------
|   Paises    | Reaudacion |
+-------------+------------+
| Argentina   |     50     |
| Argentina   |     20     |
| Argentina   |     30     |
| Brasil      |     70     |
| Brasil      |     10     |
| Brasil      |     20     |
| Ecuador     |     15     |
| Ecuador     |     25     |
| Etc         |      -     |
+-------------+------------+
```

Lo que estoy intentando es que se me unifiquen los paises (no que se sumen) y las remuneraciones de los paises se sumen (las que correspondan a cada uno). Asi quedaria:

```
+-------------+------------+
|   Paises    | Reaudacion |
+-------------+------------+
| Argentina   |    100     |   
| Brasil      |    100     |
| Ecuador     |     40     |
| Etc         |      -     |
+-------------+------------+
```

Dejo mi codigo, por si ademas se puede hacer algun arreglo de estetica o se puede hacer de manera mas practica. Gracias

```
**SELECT 
    paises.pais as paises,
    pagos.cantidad * peliculas.precio_renta AS recaudacion
FROM 
    rentas
    INNER JOIN inventarios ON rentas.inventario_id = inventarios.inventario_id
    INNER JOIN peliculas ON inventarios.pelicula_id = peliculas.pelicula_id
    INNER JOIN pagos ON rentas.renta_id = pagos.renta_id
    INNER JOIN clientes ON pagos.cliente_id = clientes.cliente_id
    INNER JOIN direcciones ON clientes.direccion_id = direcciones.direccion_id
    INNER JOIN ciudades ON direcciones.ciudad_id = ciudades.ciudad_id
    INNER JOIN paises ON ciudades.pais_id = paises.pais_id
GROUP BY  recaudacion, paises
ORDER BY paises asc**
```

Comment: Este código te da la primera tabla que haz colocado de ejemplo?

Comment: Hola compañero! Las dos primeras tablas (que contienen solo 3 paises) es el ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr.
El codigo de sql es el codigo que escribi, en donde quiza el error lo tengo por algun lado del codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es esto:

```sql
Select a.paises, sum(a.recaudacion) 
FROM (
SELECT 
    paises.pais as paises,
    pagos.cantidad * peliculas.precio_renta AS recaudacion
FROM 
    rentas
    INNER JOIN inventarios ON rentas.inventario_id = inventarios.inventario_id
    INNER JOIN peliculas ON inventarios.pelicula_id = peliculas.pelicula_id
    INNER JOIN pagos ON rentas.renta_id = pagos.renta_id
    INNER JOIN clientes ON pagos.cliente_id = clientes.cliente_id
    INNER JOIN direcciones ON clientes.direccion_id = direcciones.direccion_id
    INNER JOIN ciudades ON direcciones.ciudad_id = ciudades.ciudad_id
    INNER JOIN paises ON ciudades.pais_id = paises.pais_id
GROUP BY  recaudacion, paises
ORDER BY paises asc ) AS a

Group by a.paises
```

Básicamente si con la consulta que tienes te trae el primer resultado (tu primera tabla) , tratala como una subquery.

Comment: Compañero Sanchez!!, me sirvió, muchísimas gracias. Voy a estar investigando mas sobre los subqueries, parecen interesantes. Me empecé a frustrar cuando no me ordenaba las recaudaciones de mayor a menor, se me arreglo agrupando por paises y ordenando por recaudación (era algo intuitivo, pero no lo veía). Que termines un buen domingo, saludos!! :)

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido. Otras formas de hacerlo es con CTE's, estás de realizan en tiempo de ejecución, pero es lo mismo prácticamente. Un abrazo.